# Which is the better approximation to $e$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $a_n = (1+1/n)^n$
and $b_n = (1+1/n)^{n+1}$.
Both $a_n \to e$
and $b_n \to e$,
and
$a_n < e < b_n$.

A better approximation to $e$
is known to be
$c_n = (1+1/n)^{n+1/2}
= \sqrt{a_n b_n}
$,
the geometric mean aof $a_n$ and $b_n$.

My question is:
how about $d_n = (a_n+b_n)/2$,
the arithmetic mean of $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Is $d_n$ a better approximation to $e$
than $c_n$?

More precisely,
let $r_n = \frac{c_n-e}{d_n-e}$.
Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} r_n$
exist? If so, is it $0$,
$\infty$, or a finite value?
If the limit is finite, what is it?

Is there some other mean of $a_n$ and $b_n$
(such as the harmonic mean)
which does better than either?

No, I haven't tried to solve these yet.
I thought they would be interesting questions.

Extra points if the answer
does $not$ use the expansions of
$\ln(1\pm x)$ or $e^x$.

Comment: You probably know that the approximations you mention are pretty bad. The standard Taylor expansion of $\exp$ gives a much much much better approximation via the usual series. So perhaps you can give some more context as to the reason to ponder upon slightly improving pretty slowly converging sequences when a very fast converging series is well-known.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We only need third-order approximations to settle this:

$$\ln a_n = n \ln(1 + 1/n) = n(1/n - 1/2n^2 + 1/3n^3 + O(1/n^4)) = 1 - 1/2n + 1/3n^2 + O(1/n^3).$$
$$\ln b_n = (n+1)(1/n - 1/2n^2 + 1/3n^3 + O(1/n^4)) = 1 + 1/2n - 1/6n^2 + O(1/n^3).$$
$$\ln c_n = \tfrac12 (\ln a_n + \ln b_n) = 1 + 1/12n^2 + O(1/n^3).$$

To get asymptotics for $d_n$, expand $a_n = e \exp(\ln a_n - 1) = e( 1 - 1/2n + 11/24n^2 + O(1/n^3))$ and
$b_n = e \exp(\ln b_n - 1) = e(1 + 1/2n - 1/24n^2 + O(1/n^3))$, to see that

$$d_n = e(1 + 5/24n^2 + O(1/n^3)),\text{ while }c_n = e(1 + 1/12n^2 + O(1/n^3)).$$

This explains why $c_n$ is the better approximation by a factor of $2/5$.

An even better approximation would be $(\tfrac12a_n^p + \tfrac12b_n^p)^{1/p}$ for $p=-2/3$, which cancels the second-order term.  Maple calculations show that this in fact also cancels the third-order term and that the coefficient of $n^{-4}$ is quite small (on the order of $1/10000$), so this approximation is surprisingly good!

For $n=100$ we get $2.718281828463159$, good to 10 decimal places and gunning for the 11th.

Comment: +1. I assume the similar/same argument would also yield that $l_n \to -0.2$.

Comment: That's the answer I wanted - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but some numerical insight. From the figure, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} r_n = 0.4$$
The red line is the line at an height of $0.4$. The limit is almost surely $0.4$, since the value of $r_{50}$ is $\approx 0.39999$. Hence, it is pretty clear that the geometric mean does a better job than the arithmetic mean, but only by a factor. Also, as Ittay Weiss has already mentioned in his comment, the convergence of both the series is actually pretty pretty slow; even for $n=50$, both the sequences, $c_n$ and $d_n$, are only accurate to the third digit.

[image]

---

Similarly, if we were to define $h_n = \dfrac2{\dfrac1{a_n} + \dfrac1{b_n}}$ and look at the sequence $$l_n = \dfrac{h_n-e}{a_n-e}$$ from the figure below we see that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} l_n = -0.2$$ The black line is at a height of $-0.2$. The limit is almost surely $-0.2$, since the value of $l_{50}$ is $\approx -0.19999$.
Also, we have
$$d_n > c_n > e > h_n$$

[image]

Comment: I credit this, but a proof would be nice. Also, how about the harmonic mean (that poor, neglected mean)?

Comment: @martycohen This is not an answer, just some quick numerical computation I did. It is interesting to prove that the limit is actually $\dfrac25$.

Comment: @martycohen Added the harmonic mean. In the meantime, Erick Wong has added a proof why $r_n \to \dfrac25$.